# how to do survdiff on two separate survival curves in R?

Tags: r, survival-analysis, survival

I have two separate survival Kaplan-Myer curve. I wonder how I can get the p value of the difference between these two survival curve. `survdiff` or `survminer::surv_pvalue` only work if there is a predictor like sex, adhere etc.

```
library(survival)
library(survminer)

fit1 <- surv_fit(Surv(time, status) ~ 1, data = colon)

colon.male = colon[colon$sex==1, ]
fit2 <- surv_fit(Surv(time, status) ~ 1, data = colon.male)
```